# .net core 3 Changing controller name, action name and domain name by culture

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

how to change domain name, controller name  according to culture on a site
for asp.net core 3.0

Urls:

```
/tr/anasayfa/index
/en/home/index
/fr/maison/index
```

There will be a single controller that will be three and will respond to more

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLocalization(opts => opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
    {
        var supportedCultures = new[]{
            new CultureInfo("tr"),
            new CultureInfo("fr"),
            new CultureInfo("en"),
        };
        options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider());
    });
    services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseRequestLocalization();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "culture-route",
        pattern: "{culture=tr}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```